# Polymer — Touchable Custom Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, polymer

I've created a simple custom element containing a [JQuery-Knob](https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob), and placed it inside a `core-scaffold` layout. When interacting with it, I notice the origin is not correct. It behaves as if the scaffold weren't there.

Another thing is that when setting the `data-width` attribute higher than 200, the bottom part of the knob gets cut off.

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

[image]

fancy_knob.html:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="fancy-knob">
  <template>
      <input type="text" value="90" id="dial" data-width="400">
  </template>
  <script type="application/javascript">
    Polymer({
        ready: function() {
            $(this.$.dial).knob();
        }
    })
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://rawgit.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob/master/dist/jquery.knob.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-scaffold/core-scaffold.html">

        <link rel="import" href="fancy_knob.html">

        <style>
            html,body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body unresolved>
        <core-scaffold>
            <fancy-knob></fancy-knob>
        </core-scaffold>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Polymer core-scaffold

To use [core-scaffold](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-scaffold), it is [mandatory](https://github.com/Polymer/core-scaffold/blob/master/core-scaffold.html) to use navigator such as [core-header-panel](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-header-panel), nav, etc

```
<body unresolved>
    <core-scaffold>
        <core-header-panel></core-header-panel>
        <fancy-knob></fancy-knob>
    </core-scaffold>
</body>
```

if you still wants to hide sidebar, do apply below style:

```
core-scaffold /deep/ core-drawer-panel /deep/ core-selector #main {
    left: 0 !important;
}
core-scaffold /deep/ core-drawer-panel /deep/ core-selector #drawer {
    width: 0 !important;
}
```

### jQuery Knob

Please specify `data-height=400` as well (default is 200).

Comment: Specifying `data-height` worked however the origin is still not correct. You almost have to try it yourself to see what I mean.

Comment: I tried and was working for me.  make sure `data-width` and `data-height` should be same. `core-scaffold` is working?

Comment: Everything shows up correctly however it doesn't behave correctly. The origin around which the knob rotates is not where it should be.

Comment: I can understand that it looks ok to you, but if you make the sidebar really wide it should become evident. If you set it to, say 400px wide, you can't even rotate the knob a full 360 degrees.

Comment: Hm, that is weird. I've tried it in several browsers and they all have the same problem. Here is an example without the custom element which works as I expect, with the mouse closely following the knob: http://jsbin.com/zajeqe/1/edit?html,output Does this behave in the exact way as in your example?

Comment: I see, i guess its a bug with jquery-knob. you can file it @ https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob